# Regex for matching a charactor that doesn't have spaces on either side

Tags: regex, dart

I have some regex that adds a space on either side of a "\n" return

```
var regex = new RegExp(r'\n');
final newString = text.replaceAll(regex, " \n ");
```

However, it keeps adding it as it matches the " \n " also.

**How would I match only a return that doesn't have spaces on either side?**

Comment: What about `\n(?! )|(?<! )\n`

Comment: You are a legend, this has been doing my head in for hours. Works perfectly.

Comment: @Jerry, that will match `\n` if it is not followed by a space or not preceded by a space. Then what? A substitution is required. Will you replace `\n` with ` \n`, `\n ` or ` \n `?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You right, but I am taking care of that in the rest of my code anyway as I then split the string by " " and process the words. This helps by seperating the words and maintaining the returns, which split by \s doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I match only a return that doesn't have spaces on either side?

Do you mean match if it doesn't have a space on at least one side, or only if it does not have a space on both sides?
That is, do you want to match the newline in `"x \ny"` or not?

If you want to match a newline which does not have spaces on both sides, you can use:

```dart
RegExp(r"(?<! )\n(?! )")
```

This will match a `\n` (newline) which is not preceded by a space and not followed by a space. That means `"x\ny"`, but none of `"x \ny"`, `"x\n y"`, and `"x \n y"`.

If you want to match newlines which already have at least one space around them, but not both, you can use the suggestion from @Jerry Jeremiah:

```dart
RegExp(r"(?!< )\n|\n(?! )");
```

This will match `"x\ny"`, `"x \ny"` and `"x\n y"`, but not `"x \n y"`.

You the replace the match with spaces, even if there is already a space on one side. That side will now have two spaces, which might be unnecessary.

If you want to avoid that, I'd go with a different approach: Match all the newlines, and replace them depending on whether they already have spaces around them:

```dart
var newlinesRE = RegExp(r"(?<=([ \n])?)\n(?=( )?)");
String flankNewlinesBySpace(String string) =>
    string.replaceAllMapped(newlinesRE, (m) => 
        "${m[1] == null ? " " : ""}\n${m[2] == null ? " " : ""}");
```

This should match every newline, and capture spaces before and after.
It replaces it with a newline. If it does not see a space or newline before, it insert a space before the newline. If it does not see a space after the newline, it inserts one.
(This should ensure that `"\n\n"` becomes `" \n \n "`, with only one space between them).

This gives a result of:

- `"x\ny"` ↦ `"x \n y"`
- `"x \ny"` ↦ `"x \n y"`
- `"x\n y"` ↦ `"x \n y"`
- `"x \n y"` ↦ `"x \n y"`
- `"x\n\ny"` ↦ `"x \n \n y"`
- `"x\n \ny"` ↦ `"x \n \n y"`
- `"x \n\n y"` ↦ `"x \n \n y"`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and explain.